# Volume busted and .exe files won't run

Tags: windows-8, audio

I've seriously been searching non-stop for the past couple days, and I can't figure out what's wrong with my computer! Could anybody help me?

For starters, the volume straight up doesn't work anymore. I've tested it with headphones in and out of my computer, neither way seems to have an effect. Whenever I try to adjust the volume, whether it's from the control panel, the mixer, or even some other miscellaneous method that requires me to access program files, it just results in whatever window I've opened up to stop responding.

And on top of all of this, none of the exe files I usually use, like Steam and Skype, will not open. It can't be a coincidence that these unrelated things began happening to my computer at the same time.

Is it possible that my computer contracted a virus at some point and that's why these basic functions can't be performed?

Comment: a combination of safe mode (on which you remove unwanted startup entries) + malware scan + `sfc /scannow` should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have had something similar before

1. For the volume, has anything with the drivers changed? Try re-installing your audio drivers.
2. About executable issue, it may be a registry issue. Previously I accidentally set all my `.exe` files to open (by default) with notepad. Try using a registry fixer that you can get in a `.cmd` or `.com` file format. If it is a file association problem, the fixer should edit the registry and fix it.

A little more on the registry: http://filext.com/faq/broken_exe_association.php